# Interface builder UIButton custom background image not working on simulator/device

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uibutton

I'm trying to do something really simple.
I have an image for a button and I'm trying to set it on a custom button in interface builder.
I set the background image accordingly (no case sensitivity problem here).
In interface builder it shows up, but in the simulator or on the device it doesn't appear at all.
Just the button's text will appear.
Do I need to turn on some flag or something of the sort?

Comment: Is the image a proper image? The IB can display more formats (like tiff) than the phone can. Make sure you don't have a tiff or psd or something that got a png extension. That usually causes this problem (which it shows up fine in IB but not on the phone).

Comment: It's a 24-bit png + transparency saved from "Save for Web" within photoshop. I don't think that's the problem

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the problem. It wasn't being linked with the Target's Copy Bundle Resources. I don't think I ever had to do this for other resources.

Shouldn't this be done automatically when you add it to the Resources of the project?